# Custom Webform Email Response to two different recipients

Tags: webforms

When a customer fills out a webform, I create a customized email response by creating a custom email template (e.g. webform-mail-26.tpl.php). I needed to create this so that the customer could see exactly what options he chose and not options he did not. The email also has some nice instructions. But I also need to send the admin an email with all the information that was in the form. How can I send two emails, one to the customer and one to the admin, but have each email display different content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing this by creating a custom email template (e.g. webform-mail-26.tpl.php). And then we created another email recipient but chose to over-ride the "default" template with a "custom" template where I used the same text and tokens as the "default" template. It was counter-intuitive but it worked.